# Ошибка решения СЛАУ

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь правильно составить слау[image: СЛАУ], чтобы решить Гауссом.
Получился примерно такой код:

```
void algorithm(int a,int b,int p)
{
    vector<int> vector1(3);
    vector<int> vector2(3);
    vector2[0] = vector1[0] = 2;
    vector2[1] = vector1[1] = 3;
    vector2[2] = vector1[2] = 5;
    int mas[3][4];
    int r = 0;
    int e = vector1.size()-1;
    int s = 1;
    int c = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            mas[i][j] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < vector1.size(); i++)
    {
        r = powmod(a,s,p);
        mas[i][3] = s+p-1;
        while (e!=-1)
        {
            if (r%vector1[e] == 0)
            {
                r /= vector1[e];
                mas[i][e]++;
            }
            else
                e--;
        }

         if(i != 0)
        {
             for (int w = i; w > 0; w--)
             {
                 for (int j = 0; j < vector1.size(); j++)
                 {
                     c += mas[w][j] * mas[w - 1][j];
                 }
             }
        }
         if ((r != 1) || (c != 0))
         {
             for (int j = 0; j < vector1.size(); j++)
                 mas[i][j]=0;
             i--;
         }

        e = vector1.size()-1;
        c = 0;
        s++;
    }
}
```

Я проверяю, чтобы уравнения были линейно независимые. По примеру получается система:

```
101 47
110 48
220 50
021 53
По моему примеру:
101 47
030 54
500 58
```

Если мой решать, то корни ответа не сходятся, где ошибка?

Comment: А что отладчик показывает?

Comment: он вот такую СЛАУ строит, которая не правильная, где я неправильно делаю?